# Add Date/Time Validation to Excel's Cell

Tags: excel, datetime, validation, vba

I have a work schedule that I have created and I would like to place some code in there that verifies the entries are a proper time format and not text.

I have the basic part of the code done but I'm having some difficulty with it searching through the various cells.  Unfortunately the cells are just one big list or it would be easy enough for my code to work.  I started to create multiple ranges and I was going to create some for statements to cycle through but I figure there must be a simpler way.  I'm new to this site so I can't attach the image of the schedule.  You can see below though in the code the various cells in my range.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

    Dim cel As Range, targ As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim DateRng As Range
    Dim Emp1a As Range, Emp1b As Range
    Dim Emp2a As Range, Emp2b As Range
    Dim Emp3a As Range, Emp3b As Range
    Dim Emp4a As Range, Emp4b As Range
    Dim Emp5a As Range, Emp5b As Range
    Dim Emp6a As Range, Emp6b As Range
    Dim Emp7a As Range, Emp7b As Range
    Dim Emp8a As Range, Emp8b As Range
    Dim Emp9a As Range, Emp9b As Range
    Dim Emp10a As Range, Emp10b As Range
    Dim Emp11a As Range, Emp11b As Range
    Dim Emp12a As Range, Emp12b As Range
    Dim Emp13a As Range, Emp13b As Range
    Dim Emp14a As Range, Emp14b As Range
    Dim Emp15a As Range, Emp15b As Range
    Dim Emp16a As Range, Emp16b As Range
    Dim Emp17a As Range, Emp17b As Range
    Dim Emp18a As Range, Emp18b As Range
    Dim Emp19a As Range, Emp19b As Range
    Dim Emp20a As Range, Emp20b As Range
    Dim Emp21a As Range, Emp21b As Range
    Dim Emp22a As Range, Emp22b As Range
    Dim Emp23a As Range, Emp23b As Range
    Dim Emp24a As Range, Emp24b As Range
    Dim Emp25a As Range, Emp25b As Range

    If target.Rows.Count >= Rows.Count Then Exit Sub


    Set Emp1a = Range("D5,E5,H5,I5,L5,M5,P5,Q5,T5,U5,X5,Y5,AB5,AC5,D6,E6,H6,I6,L6,M6,P6,Q6,T6,U6,X6,Y6,AB6,AC6,D7,E7,H7,I7,L7,M7,P7,Q7,T7,U7,X7,Y7,AB7,AC7")
    Set Emp1b = Range("D9,E9,H9,I9,L9,M9,P9,Q9,T9,U9,X9,Y9,AB9,AC9,D10,E10,H10,I10,L10,M10,P10,Q10,T10,U10,X10,Y10,AB10,AC10,D11,E11,H11,I11,L11,M11,P11,Q11,T11,U11,X11,Y11,AB11,AC11")
    Set Emp2a = Range("D13,E13,H13,I13,L13,M13,P13,Q13,T13,U13,X13,Y13,AB13,AC13,D14,E14,H14,I14,L14,M14,P14,Q14,T14,U14,X14,Y14,AB14,AC14,D15,E15,H15,I15,L15,M15,P15,Q15,T15,U15,X15,Y15,AB15,AC15")
    Set Emp2b = Range("D17,E17,H17,I17,L17,M17,P17,Q17,T17,U17,X17,Y17,AB17,AC17,D18,E18,H18,I18,L18,M18,P18,Q18,T18,U18,X18,Y18,AB18,AC18,D19,E19,H19,I19,L19,M19,P19,Q19,T19,U19,X19,Y19,AB19,AC19")
    Set Emp3a = Range("D25,E25,H25,I25,L25,M25,P25,Q25,T25,U25,X25,Y25,AB25,AC25,D26,E26,H26,I26,L26,M26,P26,Q26,T26,U26,X26,Y26,AB26,AC26,D27,E27,H27,I27,L27,M27,P27,Q27,T27,U27,X27,Y27,AB27,AC27")
    Set Emp3b = Range("D33,E33,H33,I33,L33,M33,P33,Q33,T33,U33,X33,Y33,AB33,AC33,D34,E34,H34,I34,L34,M34,P34,Q34,T34,U34,X34,Y34,AB34,AC34,D35,E35,H35,I35,L35,M35,P35,Q35,T35,U35,X35,Y35,AB35,AC35")

    'Watch these cells for time entries"

    Set Emp1a = Intersect(Emp1a, target) 'Watch these cells for time entries

    If Not Emp1a Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each cel In Emp1a.Cells
            If IsNumeric(cel.Value) Then
                If cel.Value > 0 Then
                    If Len(cel.Value) < 7 Then
                        On Error Resume Next
                        v = 0
                        v = TimeValue(Format(cel.Value, "00:0#"))
                        On Error GoTo 0
                        If v = 0 Then
                            cel.Select
                            MsgBox Format(cel.Value, "00:0#") & " is not a permissible time value!"
                            cel.ClearContents
                        End If

                    End If
                Else
                    If cel.Value < 0 Then
                        cel.Select
                        MsgBox cel.Value & " is not a permissible time value"
                        cel.ClearContents
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                cel.Select
                MsgBox cel.Value & " is not a permissible time value"
                cel.ClearContents
            End If
        Next
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Validation Object to a single cell or entire Range (e.g. "A1:A10") programmatically using VBA like shown in the following code snippet:

```
Sub AddTimeValidation()

With Range("A1:A10").Validation
 .Add Type:=xlValidateTime, _
 AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
 Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="0:00:00", Formula2:="23:59:59"
 .InputTitle = "Time"
 .ErrorTitle = "Time"
 .InputMessage = "Enter a Valid Time"
 .ErrorMessage = "You must enter a Enter a Valid Time"
End With

End Sub
```

Also, you can add this Validation manually (detailed explanation available here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/apply-data-validation-to-cells-HP010072600.aspx).

Hope this will help.
Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is sufficient for you, but rather than checking the cells after they have entered information it may be easier to prevent them from entering it. Its a two step process

1. Simply select the cells > right click > Format cells.. > Time > select the appropriate representation. This only changes the way the cell display info
2. Select the cells > click on "data" from ribbon > Click Data Validation > Allow: "Time" > then for Data you can use 
   between" 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 (for any valid date) or adjust it as necessary

This will do what you want, but not in a vba fashion. I say why re-invent the wheel? Plus the built-in functions are tested and generally very robust

-------------------edit: how to run on cell change----------------------
I highly recommend this. http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm They key here is that instead of entering the code in a regular "module" you actually enter the code in the sheet itself just double click the sheet name in vb explorer and a window to enter code will appear (I'm guessing that was your issue). Use the function header exactly as it is (which you are)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'do not change the stuff up there ^^^^
    'do whatever you want to the stuff down below vvvv
    MsgBox "You just changed " & Target.Address
End Sub
```

It will automatically run as soon as any change is made to that specific sheet. Now since you only want it to run when certain cells are changed you add an range(also on the link). Since you have so many, and such long ranges I would make them global to save time especially if you need them in other functions you may write. I also think it is easier to read. If you don't know global variables can be accessed from anywhere. They are shared across all functions/subs. So move your declarations to the top of the worksheet module (thats what im calling the place you entered the worksheet_change sub).

```html
Dim Emp1 As Range, Emp2 As Range
Dim Emp3 As Range, Emp4 As Range
Dim Emp5 As Range, Emp6 As Range
Dim Emp7 As Range, Emp8 As Range
Dim Emp9 As Range, Emp10 As Range
Dim Emp11 As Range, Emp12 As Range
Dim Emp13 As Range, Emp14 As Range
Dim Emp15 As Range, Emp16 As Range
Dim Emp17 As Range, Emp18 As Range
Dim Emp19 As Range, Emp20 As Range
Dim Emp21 As Range, Emp22 As Range
Dim Emp23 As Range, Emp24 As Range
Dim Emp25 As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    
    Dim cel As Range
    
    Dim StartTime As Date
    Dim EndTime As Date
    Dim DateRng As Range
    Dim EmpHrs As Range
    Dim Emp1a As Range
    
    Call InitGlobals
    Set EmpHrs = Union(Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5, Emp6, Emp7, Emp8, Emp9, Emp10, Emp11, Emp12, Emp13, Emp14, Emp15, Emp16, Emp17, Emp18, Emp19, Emp20, Emp21, Emp22, Emp23, Emp24, Emp25)
    
    Set EmpHrs = Intersect(EmpHrs, target)
    
    'if the change isn't inside your range just quit
    If Not Intersect(target, EmpHours) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'otherwise it will continue and actually process the change
    For Each cel In EmpHrs
       StartTime = cel.Offset(0, -2)
       EndTime = cel.Offset(0, -1)
       cel = Abs((EndTime - StartTime) - (StartTime > EndTime)) * 24
    Next
        

End Sub

Private Sub InitGlobals()
    Set Emp1 = Range("F5,J5,N5,R5,V5,Z5,AD5,F6,J6,N6,R6,V6,O6,Z6,AD6,F7,J7,N7,R7,V7,AD7,F9,J9,N9,R9,V9,Z9,AD9,F10,J10,N10,R10,V10,Z10,AD10,F11,J11,N11,R11,V11,Z11,AD11")
    Set Emp2 = Range("F13,J13,N13,R13,V13,Z13,AD13,F14,J14,N14,R14,V14,Z14,AD14,F15,J15,N15,R15,V15,Z15,AD15,F17,J17,N17,R17,V17,Z17,AD17,F18,J18,N18,R18,V18,Z18,AD18,F19,J19,N19,R19,V19,Z19,AD19")
    Set Emp3 = Range("F21,J21,N21,R21,V21,Z21,AD21,F22,J22,N22,R22,V22,Z22,AD22,F23,J23,N23,R23,V23,Z23,AD23,F25,J25,N25,R25,V25,Z25,AD25,F26,J26,N26,R26,V26,Z26,AD26,F27,J27,N27,R27,V27,Z27,AD27")
    Set Emp4 = Range("F29,J29,N29,R29,V29,Z29,AD29,F30,J30,N30,R30,V30,Z30,AD30,F31,J31,N31,R31,V31,Z31,AD31,F33,J33,N33,R33,V33,Z33,AD33,F34,J34,N34,R34,V34,Z34,AD34,F35,J35,N35,R35,V35,Z35,AD35")
    Set Emp5 = Range("F37,J37,N37,R37,V37,Z37,AD37,F38,J38,N38,R38,V38,Z38,AD38,F39,J39,N39,R39,V39,Z39,AD39,F41,J41,N41,R41,V41,Z41,AD41,F42,J42,N42,R42,V42,Z42,AD42,F43,J43,N43,R43,V43,Z43,AD43")
    Set Emp6 = Range("F49,J49,N49,R49,V49,Z49,AD49,F50,J50,N50,R50,V50,Z50,AD50,F51,J51,N51,R51,V51,Z51,AD51,F53,J53,N53,R53,V53,Z53,AD53,F54,J54,N54,R54,V54,Z54,AD54,F55,J55,N55,R55,V55,Z55,AD55")
    Set Emp7 = Range("F57,J57,N57,R57,V57,Z57,AD57,F58,J58,N58,R58,V58,Z58,AD58,F59,J59,N59,R59,V59,Z59,AD59,F61,J61,N61,R61,V61,Z61,AD61,F62,J62,N62,R62,V62,Z62,AD62,F63,J63,N63,R63,V63,Z63,AD6")
    Set Emp8 = Range("F65,J65,N65,R65,V65,Z65,AD65,F66,J66,N66,R66,V66,Z66,AD66,F67,J67,N67,R67,V67,Z67,AD67,F69,J69,N69,R69,V69,Z69,AD69,F70,J70,N70,R70,V70,Z70,AD70,F71,J71,N71,R71,V71,Z71,AD71")
    Set Emp9 = Range("F73,J73,N73,R73,V73,Z73,AD73,F74,J74,N74,R74,V74,Z74,AD74,F75,J75,N75,R75,V75,Z75,AD75,F77,J77,N77,R77,V77,Z77,AD77,F78,J78,N78,R78,V78,Z78,AD78,F79,J79,N79,R79,V79,Z79,AD79")
    Set Emp10 = Range("F81,J81,N81,R81,V81,Z81,AD81,F82,J82,N82,R82,V82,Z82,AD82,F83,J83,N83,R83,V83,Z83,AD83,F85,J85,N85,R85,V85,Z85,AD85,F86,J86,N86,R86,V86,Z86,AD86,F87,J87,N87,R87,V87,Z87,AD87")
    Set Emp11 = Range("F93,J93,N93,R93,V93,Z93,AD93,F94,J94,N94,R94,V94,Z94,AD94,F95,J95,N95,R95,V95,Z95,AD95,F97,J97,N97,R97,V97,Z97,AD97,F98,J98,N98,R98,V98,Z98,AD98,F99,J99,N99,R99,V99,Z99,AD99")
    Set Emp12 = Range("F101,J101,N101,R101,V101,Z101,AD101,F102,J102,N102,R102,V102,Z102,AD102,F103,J103,N103,R103,V103,Z103,AD103,F105,J105,N105,R105,V105,Z105,AD105,F106,J106,N106,R106,V106,Z106,AD106,F107,J107,N107,R107,V107,Z107,AD107")
    Set Emp13 = Range("F109,J109,N109,R109,V109,Z109,AD109,F110,J110,N110,R110,V110,Z110,AD110,F111,J111,N111,R111,V111,Z111,AD111,F113,J113,N113,R113,V113,Z113,AD113,F114,J114,N114,R114,V114,Z114,AD114,F115,J115,N115,R115,V115,Z115,AD115")
    Set Emp14 = Range("F117,J117,N117,R117,V117,Z117,AD117,F118,J118,N118,R118,V118,Z118,AD118,F119,J119,N119,R119,V119,Z119,AD119,F121,J121,N121,R121,V121,Z121,AD121,F122,J122,N122,R122,V122,Z122,AD122,F123,J123,N123,R123,V123,Z123,AD123")
    Set Emp15 = Range("F125,J125,N125,R125,V125,Z125,AD125,F126,J126,N126,R126,V126,Z126,AD126,F127,J127,N127,R127,V127,Z127,AD127,F129,J129,N129,R129,V129,Z129,AD129,F130,J130,N130,R130,V130,Z130,AD130,F131,J131,N131,R131,V131,Z131,AD131")
    Set Emp16 = Range("F137,J137,N137,R137,V137,Z137,AD137,F138,J138,N138,R138,V138,Z138,AD138,F139,J139,N139,R139,V139,Z139,AD139,F141,J141,N141,R141,V141,Z141,AD141,F142,J142,N142,R142,V142,Z142,AD142,F143,J143,N143,R143,V143,Z143,AD143")
    Set Emp17 = Range("F145,J145,N145,R145,V145,Z145,AD145,F146,J146,N146,R146,V146,Z146,AD146,F147,J147,N147,R147,V147,Z147,AD147,F149,J149,N149,R149,V149,Z149,AD149,F150,J150,N150,R150,V150,Z150,AD150,F151,J151,N151,R151,V151,Z151,AD151")
    Set Emp18 = Range("F153,J153,N153,R153,V153,Z153,AD153,F154,J154,N154,R154,V154,Z154,AD154,F155,J155,N155,R155,V155,Z155,AD155,F157,J157,N157,R157,V157,Z157,AD157,F158,J158,N158,R158,V158,Z158,AD158,F159,J159,N159,R159,V159,Z159,AD159")
    Set Emp19 = Range("F161,J161,N161,R161,V161,Z161,AD161,F162,J162,N162,R162,V162,Z162,AD162,F163,J163,N163,R163,V163,Z163,AD163,F165,J165,N165,R165,V165,Z165,AD165,F166,J166,N166,R166,V166,Z166,AD166,F167,J167,N167,R167,V167,Z167,AD167")
    Set Emp20 = Range("F169,J169,N169,R169,V169,Z169,AD169,F170,J170,N170,R170,V170,Z170,AD170,F171,J171,N171,R171,V171,Z171,AD171,F173,J173,N173,R173,V173,Z173,AD173,F174,J174,N174,R174,V174,Z174,AD174,F175,J175,N175,R175,V175,Z175,AD175")
    Set Emp21 = Range("F181,J181,N181,R181,V181,Z181,AD181,F182,J182,N182,R182,V182,Z182,AD182,F183,J183,N183,R183,V183,Z183,AD183,F185,J185,N185,R185,V185,Z185,AD185,F186,J186,N186,R186,V186,Z186,AD186,F187,J187,N187,R187,V187,Z187,AD187")
    Set Emp22 = Range("F189,J189,N189,R189,V189,Z189,AD189,F190,J190,N190,R190,V190,Z190,AD190,F191,J191,N191,R191,V191,Z191,AD191,F193,J193,N193,R193,V193,Z193,AD193,F194,J194,N194,R194,V194,Z194,AD194,F195,J195,N195,R195,V195,Z195,AD195")
    Set Emp23 = Range("F197,J197,N197,R197,V197,Z197,AD197,F198,J198,N198,R198,V198,Z198,AD198,F199,J199,N199,R199,V199,Z199,AD199,F201,J201,N201,R201,V201,Z201,AD201,F202,J202,N202,R202,V202,Z202,AD202,F203,J203,N203,R203,V203,Z203,AD203")
    Set Emp24 = Range("F205,J205,N205,R205,V205,Z205,AD205,F206,J206,N206,R206,V206,Z206,AD206,F207,J207,N207,R207,V207,Z207,AD207,F209,J209,N209,R209,V209,Z209,AD209,F210,J210,N210,R210,V210,Z210,AD210,F211,J211,N211,R211,V211,Z211,AD211")
    Set Emp25 = Range("F213,J213,N213,R213,V213,Z213,AD213,F214,J214,N214,R214,V214,Z214,AD214,F215,J215,N215,R215,V215,Z215,AD215,F217,J217,N217,R217,V217,Z217,AD217,F218,J218,N218,R218,V218,Z218,AD218,F219,J219,N219,R219,V219,Z219,AD219")

End Sub
```

And the main thing to note is i added this 
   `If Not Intersect(target, EmpHours) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If`

you were headed in the right direction though which basically just says if the cell wasn't in the range quit the sub. Hope that helped

Comment: Okay I used Data Validation.  Never thought of that.  However, I have the same problem for when i'm calculating the hours.  So I will still need to do above. with the varying data ranges of individual cells.  suggestions?

Comment: Just to clarify was your problem "Searching through the various cells"?? If so you can create a range that is a comma delimited list say  **my_range = "a1,b3,d275,aa13"** then use something like **Set Rng=Range(my_range)** then do **For Each cell In rng '(do your operations, to get the cells val simply use cell.value) next**

hope that helped

Comment: my comments are bellow.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use data validation for my dates. 
Plus I was able to get my to get my code working the way I wanted it in a command button.  Which is to calculate the hours of each of the time ranges.

But now I would like to have my code to work as a change event.   Here is all my code below

**Command Button Code**

```html
Command Button Code

    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim StartTime As Date
Dim EndTime As Date
Dim DateRng As Range
Dim EmpHrs As Range
Dim Emp1 As Range, Emp2 As Range
Dim Emp3 As Range, Emp4 As Range
Dim Emp5 As Range, Emp6 As Range
Dim Emp7 As Range, Emp8 As Range
Dim Emp9 As Range, Emp10 As Range
Dim Emp11 As Range, Emp12 As Range
Dim Emp13 As Range, Emp14 As Range
Dim Emp15 As Range, Emp16 As Range
Dim Emp17 As Range, Emp18 As Range
Dim Emp19 As Range, Emp20 As Range
Dim Emp21 As Range, Emp22 As Range
Dim Emp23 As Range, Emp24 As Range
Dim Emp25 As Range

Set Emp1 = Range("F5,J5,N5,R5,V5,Z5,AD5,F6,J6,N6,R6,V6,O6,Z6,AD6,F7,J7,N7,R7,V7,AD7,F9,J9,N9,R9,V9,Z9,AD9,F10,J10,N10,R10,V10,Z10,AD10,F11,J11,N11,R11,V11,Z11,AD11")
Set Emp2 = Range("F13,J13,N13,R13,V13,Z13,AD13,F14,J14,N14,R14,V14,Z14,AD14,F15,J15,N15,R15,V15,Z15,AD15,F17,J17,N17,R17,V17,Z17,AD17,F18,J18,N18,R18,V18,Z18,AD18,F19,J19,N19,R19,V19,Z19,AD19")
Set Emp3 = Range("F21,J21,N21,R21,V21,Z21,AD21,F22,J22,N22,R22,V22,Z22,AD22,F23,J23,N23,R23,V23,Z23,AD23,F25,J25,N25,R25,V25,Z25,AD25,F26,J26,N26,R26,V26,Z26,AD26,F27,J27,N27,R27,V27,Z27,AD27")
Set Emp4 = Range("F29,J29,N29,R29,V29,Z29,AD29,F30,J30,N30,R30,V30,Z30,AD30,F31,J31,N31,R31,V31,Z31,AD31,F33,J33,N33,R33,V33,Z33,AD33,F34,J34,N34,R34,V34,Z34,AD34,F35,J35,N35,R35,V35,Z35,AD35")
Set Emp5 = Range("F37,J37,N37,R37,V37,Z37,AD37,F38,J38,N38,R38,V38,Z38,AD38,F39,J39,N39,R39,V39,Z39,AD39,F41,J41,N41,R41,V41,Z41,AD41,F42,J42,N42,R42,V42,Z42,AD42,F43,J43,N43,R43,V43,Z43,AD43")
Set Emp6 = Range("F49,J49,N49,R49,V49,Z49,AD49,F50,J50,N50,R50,V50,Z50,AD50,F51,J51,N51,R51,V51,Z51,AD51,F53,J53,N53,R53,V53,Z53,AD53,F54,J54,N54,R54,V54,Z54,AD54,F55,J55,N55,R55,V55,Z55,AD55")
Set Emp7 = Range("F57,J57,N57,R57,V57,Z57,AD57,F58,J58,N58,R58,V58,Z58,AD58,F59,J59,N59,R59,V59,Z59,AD59,F61,J61,N61,R61,V61,Z61,AD61,F62,J62,N62,R62,V62,Z62,AD62,F63,J63,N63,R63,V63,Z63,AD6")
Set Emp8 = Range("F65,J65,N65,R65,V65,Z65,AD65,F66,J66,N66,R66,V66,Z66,AD66,F67,J67,N67,R67,V67,Z67,AD67,F69,J69,N69,R69,V69,Z69,AD69,F70,J70,N70,R70,V70,Z70,AD70,F71,J71,N71,R71,V71,Z71,AD71")
Set Emp9 = Range("F73,J73,N73,R73,V73,Z73,AD73,F74,J74,N74,R74,V74,Z74,AD74,F75,J75,N75,R75,V75,Z75,AD75,F77,J77,N77,R77,V77,Z77,AD77,F78,J78,N78,R78,V78,Z78,AD78,F79,J79,N79,R79,V79,Z79,AD79")
Set Emp10 = Range("F81,J81,N81,R81,V81,Z81,AD81,F82,J82,N82,R82,V82,Z82,AD82,F83,J83,N83,R83,V83,Z83,AD83,F85,J85,N85,R85,V85,Z85,AD85,F86,J86,N86,R86,V86,Z86,AD86,F87,J87,N87,R87,V87,Z87,AD87")
Set Emp11 = Range("F93,J93,N93,R93,V93,Z93,AD93,F94,J94,N94,R94,V94,Z94,AD94,F95,J95,N95,R95,V95,Z95,AD95,F97,J97,N97,R97,V97,Z97,AD97,F98,J98,N98,R98,V98,Z98,AD98,F99,J99,N99,R99,V99,Z99,AD99")
Set Emp12 = Range("F101,J101,N101,R101,V101,Z101,AD101,F102,J102,N102,R102,V102,Z102,AD102,F103,J103,N103,R103,V103,Z103,AD103,F105,J105,N105,R105,V105,Z105,AD105,F106,J106,N106,R106,V106,Z106,AD106,F107,J107,N107,R107,V107,Z107,AD107")
Set Emp13 = Range("F109,J109,N109,R109,V109,Z109,AD109,F110,J110,N110,R110,V110,Z110,AD110,F111,J111,N111,R111,V111,Z111,AD111,F113,J113,N113,R113,V113,Z113,AD113,F114,J114,N114,R114,V114,Z114,AD114,F115,J115,N115,R115,V115,Z115,AD115")
Set Emp14 = Range("F117,J117,N117,R117,V117,Z117,AD117,F118,J118,N118,R118,V118,Z118,AD118,F119,J119,N119,R119,V119,Z119,AD119,F121,J121,N121,R121,V121,Z121,AD121,F122,J122,N122,R122,V122,Z122,AD122,F123,J123,N123,R123,V123,Z123,AD123")
Set Emp15 = Range("F125,J125,N125,R125,V125,Z125,AD125,F126,J126,N126,R126,V126,Z126,AD126,F127,J127,N127,R127,V127,Z127,AD127,F129,J129,N129,R129,V129,Z129,AD129,F130,J130,N130,R130,V130,Z130,AD130,F131,J131,N131,R131,V131,Z131,AD131")
Set Emp16 = Range("F137,J137,N137,R137,V137,Z137,AD137,F138,J138,N138,R138,V138,Z138,AD138,F139,J139,N139,R139,V139,Z139,AD139,F141,J141,N141,R141,V141,Z141,AD141,F142,J142,N142,R142,V142,Z142,AD142,F143,J143,N143,R143,V143,Z143,AD143")
Set Emp17 = Range("F145,J145,N145,R145,V145,Z145,AD145,F146,J146,N146,R146,V146,Z146,AD146,F147,J147,N147,R147,V147,Z147,AD147,F149,J149,N149,R149,V149,Z149,AD149,F150,J150,N150,R150,V150,Z150,AD150,F151,J151,N151,R151,V151,Z151,AD151")
Set Emp18 = Range("F153,J153,N153,R153,V153,Z153,AD153,F154,J154,N154,R154,V154,Z154,AD154,F155,J155,N155,R155,V155,Z155,AD155,F157,J157,N157,R157,V157,Z157,AD157,F158,J158,N158,R158,V158,Z158,AD158,F159,J159,N159,R159,V159,Z159,AD159")
Set Emp19 = Range("F161,J161,N161,R161,V161,Z161,AD161,F162,J162,N162,R162,V162,Z162,AD162,F163,J163,N163,R163,V163,Z163,AD163,F165,J165,N165,R165,V165,Z165,AD165,F166,J166,N166,R166,V166,Z166,AD166,F167,J167,N167,R167,V167,Z167,AD167")
Set Emp20 = Range("F169,J169,N169,R169,V169,Z169,AD169,F170,J170,N170,R170,V170,Z170,AD170,F171,J171,N171,R171,V171,Z171,AD171,F173,J173,N173,R173,V173,Z173,AD173,F174,J174,N174,R174,V174,Z174,AD174,F175,J175,N175,R175,V175,Z175,AD175")
Set Emp21 = Range("F181,J181,N181,R181,V181,Z181,AD181,F182,J182,N182,R182,V182,Z182,AD182,F183,J183,N183,R183,V183,Z183,AD183,F185,J185,N185,R185,V185,Z185,AD185,F186,J186,N186,R186,V186,Z186,AD186,F187,J187,N187,R187,V187,Z187,AD187")
Set Emp22 = Range("F189,J189,N189,R189,V189,Z189,AD189,F190,J190,N190,R190,V190,Z190,AD190,F191,J191,N191,R191,V191,Z191,AD191,F193,J193,N193,R193,V193,Z193,AD193,F194,J194,N194,R194,V194,Z194,AD194,F195,J195,N195,R195,V195,Z195,AD195")
Set Emp23 = Range("F197,J197,N197,R197,V197,Z197,AD197,F198,J198,N198,R198,V198,Z198,AD198,F199,J199,N199,R199,V199,Z199,AD199,F201,J201,N201,R201,V201,Z201,AD201,F202,J202,N202,R202,V202,Z202,AD202,F203,J203,N203,R203,V203,Z203,AD203")
Set Emp24 = Range("F205,J205,N205,R205,V205,Z205,AD205,F206,J206,N206,R206,V206,Z206,AD206,F207,J207,N207,R207,V207,Z207,AD207,F209,J209,N209,R209,V209,Z209,AD209,F210,J210,N210,R210,V210,Z210,AD210,F211,J211,N211,R211,V211,Z211,AD211")
Set Emp25 = Range("F213,J213,N213,R213,V213,Z213,AD213,F214,J214,N214,R214,V214,Z214,AD214,F215,J215,N215,R215,V215,Z215,AD215,F217,J217,N217,R217,V217,Z217,AD217,F218,J218,N218,R218,V218,Z218,AD218,F219,J219,N219,R219,V219,Z219,AD219")

Set EmpHrs = Union(Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5, Emp6, Emp7, Emp8, Emp9, Emp10, Emp11, Emp12, Emp13, Emp14, Emp15, Emp16, Emp17, Emp18, Emp19, Emp20, Emp21, Emp22, Emp23, Emp24, Emp25)
For Each DateRng In EmpHrs

  
On Error Resume Next
    StartTime = DateRng.Offset(0, -2)
    EndTime = DateRng.Offset(0, -1)
    DateRng = Abs((EndTime - StartTime) - (StartTime > EndTime)) * 24

Next DateRng

   
End Sub
```

**Change Event Code**

```html
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

Dim cel As Range

Dim StartTime As Date
Dim EndTime As Date
Dim DateRng As Range
Dim EmpHrs As Range
Dim Emp1a As Range

Dim Emp1 As Range, Emp2 As Range
Dim Emp3 As Range, Emp4 As Range
Dim Emp5 As Range, Emp6 As Range
Dim Emp7 As Range, Emp8 As Range
Dim Emp9 As Range, Emp10 As Range
Dim Emp11 As Range, Emp12 As Range
Dim Emp13 As Range, Emp14 As Range
Dim Emp15 As Range, Emp16 As Range
Dim Emp17 As Range, Emp18 As Range
Dim Emp19 As Range, Emp20 As Range
Dim Emp21 As Range, Emp22 As Range
Dim Emp23 As Range, Emp24 As Range
Dim Emp25 As Range

Set Emp1 = Range("F5,J5,N5,R5,V5,Z5,AD5,F6,J6,N6,R6,V6,O6,Z6,AD6,F7,J7,N7,R7,V7,AD7,F9,J9,N9,R9,V9,Z9,AD9,F10,J10,N10,R10,V10,Z10,AD10,F11,J11,N11,R11,V11,Z11,AD11")
Set Emp2 = Range("F13,J13,N13,R13,V13,Z13,AD13,F14,J14,N14,R14,V14,Z14,AD14,F15,J15,N15,R15,V15,Z15,AD15,F17,J17,N17,R17,V17,Z17,AD17,F18,J18,N18,R18,V18,Z18,AD18,F19,J19,N19,R19,V19,Z19,AD19")
Set Emp3 = Range("F21,J21,N21,R21,V21,Z21,AD21,F22,J22,N22,R22,V22,Z22,AD22,F23,J23,N23,R23,V23,Z23,AD23,F25,J25,N25,R25,V25,Z25,AD25,F26,J26,N26,R26,V26,Z26,AD26,F27,J27,N27,R27,V27,Z27,AD27")
Set Emp4 = Range("F29,J29,N29,R29,V29,Z29,AD29,F30,J30,N30,R30,V30,Z30,AD30,F31,J31,N31,R31,V31,Z31,AD31,F33,J33,N33,R33,V33,Z33,AD33,F34,J34,N34,R34,V34,Z34,AD34,F35,J35,N35,R35,V35,Z35,AD35")
Set Emp5 = Range("F37,J37,N37,R37,V37,Z37,AD37,F38,J38,N38,R38,V38,Z38,AD38,F39,J39,N39,R39,V39,Z39,AD39,F41,J41,N41,R41,V41,Z41,AD41,F42,J42,N42,R42,V42,Z42,AD42,F43,J43,N43,R43,V43,Z43,AD43")
Set Emp6 = Range("F49,J49,N49,R49,V49,Z49,AD49,F50,J50,N50,R50,V50,Z50,AD50,F51,J51,N51,R51,V51,Z51,AD51,F53,J53,N53,R53,V53,Z53,AD53,F54,J54,N54,R54,V54,Z54,AD54,F55,J55,N55,R55,V55,Z55,AD55")
Set Emp7 = Range("F57,J57,N57,R57,V57,Z57,AD57,F58,J58,N58,R58,V58,Z58,AD58,F59,J59,N59,R59,V59,Z59,AD59,F61,J61,N61,R61,V61,Z61,AD61,F62,J62,N62,R62,V62,Z62,AD62,F63,J63,N63,R63,V63,Z63,AD6")
Set Emp8 = Range("F65,J65,N65,R65,V65,Z65,AD65,F66,J66,N66,R66,V66,Z66,AD66,F67,J67,N67,R67,V67,Z67,AD67,F69,J69,N69,R69,V69,Z69,AD69,F70,J70,N70,R70,V70,Z70,AD70,F71,J71,N71,R71,V71,Z71,AD71")
Set Emp9 = Range("F73,J73,N73,R73,V73,Z73,AD73,F74,J74,N74,R74,V74,Z74,AD74,F75,J75,N75,R75,V75,Z75,AD75,F77,J77,N77,R77,V77,Z77,AD77,F78,J78,N78,R78,V78,Z78,AD78,F79,J79,N79,R79,V79,Z79,AD79")
Set Emp10 = Range("F81,J81,N81,R81,V81,Z81,AD81,F82,J82,N82,R82,V82,Z82,AD82,F83,J83,N83,R83,V83,Z83,AD83,F85,J85,N85,R85,V85,Z85,AD85,F86,J86,N86,R86,V86,Z86,AD86,F87,J87,N87,R87,V87,Z87,AD87")
Set Emp11 = Range("F93,J93,N93,R93,V93,Z93,AD93,F94,J94,N94,R94,V94,Z94,AD94,F95,J95,N95,R95,V95,Z95,AD95,F97,J97,N97,R97,V97,Z97,AD97,F98,J98,N98,R98,V98,Z98,AD98,F99,J99,N99,R99,V99,Z99,AD99")
Set Emp12 = Range("F101,J101,N101,R101,V101,Z101,AD101,F102,J102,N102,R102,V102,Z102,AD102,F103,J103,N103,R103,V103,Z103,AD103,F105,J105,N105,R105,V105,Z105,AD105,F106,J106,N106,R106,V106,Z106,AD106,F107,J107,N107,R107,V107,Z107,AD107")
Set Emp13 = Range("F109,J109,N109,R109,V109,Z109,AD109,F110,J110,N110,R110,V110,Z110,AD110,F111,J111,N111,R111,V111,Z111,AD111,F113,J113,N113,R113,V113,Z113,AD113,F114,J114,N114,R114,V114,Z114,AD114,F115,J115,N115,R115,V115,Z115,AD115")
Set Emp14 = Range("F117,J117,N117,R117,V117,Z117,AD117,F118,J118,N118,R118,V118,Z118,AD118,F119,J119,N119,R119,V119,Z119,AD119,F121,J121,N121,R121,V121,Z121,AD121,F122,J122,N122,R122,V122,Z122,AD122,F123,J123,N123,R123,V123,Z123,AD123")
Set Emp15 = Range("F125,J125,N125,R125,V125,Z125,AD125,F126,J126,N126,R126,V126,Z126,AD126,F127,J127,N127,R127,V127,Z127,AD127,F129,J129,N129,R129,V129,Z129,AD129,F130,J130,N130,R130,V130,Z130,AD130,F131,J131,N131,R131,V131,Z131,AD131")
Set Emp16 = Range("F137,J137,N137,R137,V137,Z137,AD137,F138,J138,N138,R138,V138,Z138,AD138,F139,J139,N139,R139,V139,Z139,AD139,F141,J141,N141,R141,V141,Z141,AD141,F142,J142,N142,R142,V142,Z142,AD142,F143,J143,N143,R143,V143,Z143,AD143")
Set Emp17 = Range("F145,J145,N145,R145,V145,Z145,AD145,F146,J146,N146,R146,V146,Z146,AD146,F147,J147,N147,R147,V147,Z147,AD147,F149,J149,N149,R149,V149,Z149,AD149,F150,J150,N150,R150,V150,Z150,AD150,F151,J151,N151,R151,V151,Z151,AD151")
Set Emp18 = Range("F153,J153,N153,R153,V153,Z153,AD153,F154,J154,N154,R154,V154,Z154,AD154,F155,J155,N155,R155,V155,Z155,AD155,F157,J157,N157,R157,V157,Z157,AD157,F158,J158,N158,R158,V158,Z158,AD158,F159,J159,N159,R159,V159,Z159,AD159")
Set Emp19 = Range("F161,J161,N161,R161,V161,Z161,AD161,F162,J162,N162,R162,V162,Z162,AD162,F163,J163,N163,R163,V163,Z163,AD163,F165,J165,N165,R165,V165,Z165,AD165,F166,J166,N166,R166,V166,Z166,AD166,F167,J167,N167,R167,V167,Z167,AD167")
Set Emp20 = Range("F169,J169,N169,R169,V169,Z169,AD169,F170,J170,N170,R170,V170,Z170,AD170,F171,J171,N171,R171,V171,Z171,AD171,F173,J173,N173,R173,V173,Z173,AD173,F174,J174,N174,R174,V174,Z174,AD174,F175,J175,N175,R175,V175,Z175,AD175")
Set Emp21 = Range("F181,J181,N181,R181,V181,Z181,AD181,F182,J182,N182,R182,V182,Z182,AD182,F183,J183,N183,R183,V183,Z183,AD183,F185,J185,N185,R185,V185,Z185,AD185,F186,J186,N186,R186,V186,Z186,AD186,F187,J187,N187,R187,V187,Z187,AD187")
Set Emp22 = Range("F189,J189,N189,R189,V189,Z189,AD189,F190,J190,N190,R190,V190,Z190,AD190,F191,J191,N191,R191,V191,Z191,AD191,F193,J193,N193,R193,V193,Z193,AD193,F194,J194,N194,R194,V194,Z194,AD194,F195,J195,N195,R195,V195,Z195,AD195")
Set Emp23 = Range("F197,J197,N197,R197,V197,Z197,AD197,F198,J198,N198,R198,V198,Z198,AD198,F199,J199,N199,R199,V199,Z199,AD199,F201,J201,N201,R201,V201,Z201,AD201,F202,J202,N202,R202,V202,Z202,AD202,F203,J203,N203,R203,V203,Z203,AD203")
Set Emp24 = Range("F205,J205,N205,R205,V205,Z205,AD205,F206,J206,N206,R206,V206,Z206,AD206,F207,J207,N207,R207,V207,Z207,AD207,F209,J209,N209,R209,V209,Z209,AD209,F210,J210,N210,R210,V210,Z210,AD210,F211,J211,N211,R211,V211,Z211,AD211")
Set Emp25 = Range("F213,J213,N213,R213,V213,Z213,AD213,F214,J214,N214,R214,V214,Z214,AD214,F215,J215,N215,R215,V215,Z215,AD215,F217,J217,N217,R217,V217,Z217,AD217,F218,J218,N218,R218,V218,Z218,AD218,F219,J219,N219,R219,V219,Z219,AD219")

Set EmpHrs = Union(Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5, Emp6, Emp7, Emp8, Emp9, Emp10, Emp11, Emp12, Emp13, Emp14, Emp15, Emp16, Emp17, Emp18, Emp19, Emp20, Emp21, Emp22, Emp23, Emp24, Emp25)



 
 Set EmpHrs = Intersect(EmpHrs, target)
 
    For Each cel In EmpHrs
       StartTime = cel.Offset(0, -2)
       EndTime = cel.Offset(0, -1)
       cel = Abs((EndTime - StartTime) - (StartTime > EndTime)) * 24
    Next
    
    
'End If
    


End Sub
```